# ActiveRecord customize "AS" identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord

some rails code like:

```
@result = Table_One.join(Table_Two, Table_Three).
where(id = '1').
group(:val1, :val2, :amount).
sum(:amount)
```

will execute sql like:

```
SELECT SUM(Table_One.amount) as table_one_amount, Table_One.val1 as table_one_val1 ....
```

Just wondering if there is a way to customize the rule of "as", so I can get some sql like

```
SELECT SUM(Table_One.amount) as t1_a, Table_One.val1 as t1_v1 ....
```